# Apple maps url won't work with string

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, maps

This is what I have, but it won't work.

```
NSString *appleMapsLink = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.apple.com/maps?q=%@",   _addressLabel.text];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:appleMapsLink];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

*My address label was obtained from the output of a google places search url
A sample text of _addressLabel.text is: 151 3rd Street, San Francisco
This code works with sample strings but not with the string I am trying to use, does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do convert your url string to percent escape first.

```
NSString *unescaped = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.apple.com/maps?q=%@",   _addressLabel.text];
NSString *escapedString = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
    NULL,
   (CFStringRef)unescaped,
    NULL,
    CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]\" "),
    kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: The escaping only needs to be done on the `_addressLabel.text` part, not the whole URL.

Comment: Thank you both, between both comments I was able to get it working

Answer (score 0):

The escaping only needs to be done on the `_addressLabel.text` part, not the whole URL.